# How to listen for an event in AngularJS component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

In AngularJS we can broadcast, and listen for events:

```
$rootScope.$emit('myEvent',$scope.data);

$rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data) {}
```

Is there any way to listen for events inside a component?

What I want to achieve is to execute some action on set of components which are repeated inside a form. Ng-repeat iterates over some model of course. Some data from the model is bound to the component. It's easy to bind function to component, so component can execute some logic, but the opposite direction doesn't seem to be so easy.

```
<div ng-repeat="someObject in mainModel.listOfObjects">
   <someControl ng-model="someObject.foo"></someControl>
   <custom-component ng-model="someObject.bar"></custom-component>
</div>
<someButton ng-click="executeActionOnAllCustomComponents()">
```

Comment: maybe this would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623412/reacting-on-angular-events-in-a-directive-without-injecting-rootscope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet is keep using the standard event emitting with `$emit()` and `$broadcast()`.
angular 1.5 introduced some new hooks and sintax but inside a component you can always inject `$rootScope` and `$scope`, and handling any event as you were used to in angular < 1.5.

**Template**:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
 <div ng-repeat="someObject in mainModel.listOfObjects">
   <someControl ng-model="someObject.foo"></someControl>
   <custom-component ng-model="someObject.bar"></custom-component>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Parent controller**:

```
angular.controller('parentController', ['$scope', function($scope){
 ..
 if(somethingHappend)
   $scope.$broadcast('event.sample', {}); //down in the scope chain
})
```

**Component**:

```
angular.component('customComponent', {
 bindings: {
  ngModel: '<' //one-way binding
 },
 controller: MyCtrl
}
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];

function MyCtrl('$scope', $rootScope){
 ..
 $scope.$on('event.sample', function(evt, data){
  //do your logic
 }


}
```

Another option, if you want to check for changes on your model (made from the othe parent scope, supposing a one-way binding on your scope variables), is to use the hook `$doCheck` which is triggered each digest cycle, as opposed to the old watch mechanism you must save your old value and compare it to the new one.

```
var self = this;
var oldModel = angular.copy(self.ngModel);
self.$doCheck = function(){
 if(self.model !== oldModel){
   //do something
 }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, grazie mille Karim!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $event as parameter to function

please see the below code.

```
<span ng-click=get($event)> click !!</span>

 $scope.get=function(ev)
{
alert(ev);
};
```

Result will be [object MouseEvent]

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJS in the Angular 2+ style:

```
'use strict';

    import {from, fromEventPattern} from 'rxjs';
    import {map, tap, switchMap, distinctUntilChanged} from 'rxjs/operators';

    export default {
        bindings: {},
        controller: function (SomeService, $rootScope) {
            const self = this;

            self.$onInit = () => {
                fromEventPattern(
                    (handler) => $rootScope.$on('@some-event', handler)
                ).pipe(
                    distinctUntilChanged((x, y) => _.isEqual(x, y)),
                    switchMap(([e, data]) => from(SomeService.getSomething()))
                ).subscribe(
                    data => console.log(data),
                    error => console.log(error)
                );

            };
        },
        templateUrl: './some-component.html'
    }
```

So the trick is to use [fromEventPattern](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEventPattern) to create Observable from AngularJS event listener:

```
fromEventPattern(
   (handler) => $rootScope.$on('@some-event', handler)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen to an event in AngularJs, use event handling directives like ng-click , ng-change etc. It will completely depend on the type of event you want to capture. For Ex :

Inside your component tmeplate add below html.

Click here

Define the function inside the component class.

For more details on AngularJS - event handling check the link :

https://www.tutespace.com/2018/11/angular-js-event-handling.html